# recordset data is not populated in txt field

Tags: vba, recordset

I am new to Access and VBA trying to explore. I have a form where there is two text boxes(txtAc & txtFirstName), I want data to be populated in txtFirstName on the basis of SQL query based on parameter of txtAc. I tried to achieve the same by recordset. Please review my code below: -

```
 Private Sub txtCust_Click()
 Dim cnn As ADODB.Connection
 Dim strSQL As String
 Dim rst As ADODB.Recordset
 Set cnn = CurrentProject.Connection
 Dim i As Integer
 Dim Records As Integer
 Dim AcN As Double
 Dim AcNo As Double
 AcN = Forms!dfrmAccount!txtAc.Value
 AcN = AcNo
 strSQL = "SELECT dtblCustomer.[FIRST_N], dtblAccount.[ACCOUNT_NO] FROM 
 dtblAccount INNER JOIN dtblCustomer ON dtblAccount.[CUSTOMER_ID] = 
 dtblCustomer.[CUSTOMER_ID] WHERE (((dtblAccount.[ACCOUNT_NO])='AcNo'))"
 Set rst = New ADODB.Recordset
 rst.CursorLocation = adUseClient
 rst.Open strSQL, cnn
 Records = rst.RecordCount
 Debug.Print rst.RecordCount
 For i = 1 To Records
 Me.txtFirstName.Value = rst.Fields!FIRST_N
 Debug.Print rst.Fields!FIRST_N
 rst.MoveNext
 Next i
 '' Clean up
rst.CLOSE
Set rst = Nothing
End Sub
```

Thanks in advance. Plz somebody help.

Comment: When I am executing this codes I am getting an error "Data Type mismatch in criterion expression"

Comment: Query only return one row?  As you are new to access, start with the usual bound form. Add your sql (omit the where part) to the forms record  source and bind the fcontrols to the fields/control source). Using Agodb on forms is mastery. VBA Integers are limited to -32768 to 32767 (16bit/2bytes), what ,may exced recordcount. Use Long instead.

Comment: Thanks for reply, Will implement the advise and post

Answer (score 0):

```
...(((dtblAccount.[ACCOUNT_NO])='AcNo'))"
```

should be

```
...(((dtblAccount.[ACCOUNT_NO])=" & AcNo & "))"
```

assuming ACCOUNT_NO is a numeric field.

You're also not populating AcNo - it will have the default value of zero.